# Alien Language Test Run

Tags: language

**Given the following sentences...**

1. The being ate the Earthling
   Chwtwobattaxkof kwmwhtiesh kielokebbexkof
2. They are ordering the Earthling
   Vophanihdiezh kielokebbexkof
3. I serve a dinner
   Bsazakiehdiazh rachatebbexkof
4. I cook a Earthling
   Krwotihdiosh kielokebbexkof
5. The beings eat Earthlings, but the Earthlings eat the beings
   Chwtwobattaxkov kwmwhdiezh kielokebbexkov naner kielokattaxkov kwmwhdiezh chwtwobebbexkov.
6. You taste the Earthling
   Gabaotihdiash kielokebbexkof
7. They served food
   Bsazakiehtiezh daxorpebbexkof
8. They are the beings
   Ohdiezh chwtwobebbexkov
9. You are the Earthling
   Ohdiash kielokebbexkof
10. Earthlings served food
    Kielokattaxkov bsazakiehtiezh daxorpebbexkov
11. You eat
    Kwmwhdiash
12. The beings taste
    Chwtwobattaxkov gabaotihdiezh

**...can you explain the grammar?**

Be careful! One of the sentences above is intentionally misspelled!

Translate the following:

1. Kielokattaxkov ohtiezh chwtwobebbexkov.
2. Ohdiash rachatebbexkof.
3. Kielokattaxkov ohdiezh daxorpebbexkov.

Comment: This is, for all intent and purposes, a sort of "test run" for a potential meta-puzzle series based on linguistic elements. As is such, any sort of feedback would be *heavily* appreciated

Comment: Would you like to clarify whether "one of these is intentionally misspelled" refers to the things _above_ it or the things _below_ it?

Comment: Fixed. One of the sentences above are misspelled

Comment: Feedback: Seems very straightforward. (Though of course I may have made mistakes by completely failing to notice subtleties.) The language is, aside from the barbarous orthography, rather similar to familiar Western European ones, even to the extent of maybe not distinguishing between "you (sg)" and "you (pl)", so there aren't a lot of surprises here. As a test run it's fine, but I think for a more serious puzzle I'd hope to see something a bit less familiar, if you see what I mean.

Comment: Also, of course: rot13("Vg'f n pbbxobbx!").

Comment: I may have simplified things too much. The original variant had you matching 10 sentences, of which contained "special" pronoun cases, indirect objects, possessives, adjectives, adverbs and prepositions

Comment: @NorthLæraðr I'd recommend focusing on specific aspects you can do differently. You can still make a linguistic puzzle that is small and focused, while keeping it interesting. What distinctions (or structures) can you make that Western European languages don't? What distinctions (or structures) can you ignore that Western European ones *do* make? Try building a puzzle around one or two interesting features (or even one or two *words*!) that work in an unusual way.

Comment: @Deusovi Thanks for the suggestion! Definitely will consider that

Comment: Since you are considering a meta-puzzle series, you might want to look into the 2019 galactic puzzle hunt if you haven’t already: https://2019.galacticpuzzlehunt.com/index.html . They had metas based off of deciphering a conlang called puflantu. They have some write-ups about it, too, but I’m not linking those in case you want to do the puzzles first and look at the answers/design philosophy after.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that

> this is a fairly simple inflected language, at least so far as we can tell from the given sentences. Inflections come after the stem but "stack".
>  **Verbs** have a stem ending in `h`, after which there is a tense marker (`d` for present, `t` for past), a connecting `i`, and an ending which in the given examples is one of the following:
>  -osh (first person singular)
>  -ash (second person)
>  -esh (third person singular)
>  -ezh (third person plural)
>  I think (though the evidence is a bit thin) that -o/-a/-e indicates person and -sh/-zh indicates number. (In earlier versions of this answer, I thought that progressive aspect was sometimes marked by a change in inflection, but I have abandoned that idea.)
>  **Nouns** have a stem ending in a consonant, after which there is a case marker (`atta` for the subject, `ebbe` for the object; these sentences don't include indirect objects, prepositions, etc.), then a connecting `xko`, then a number marker (`f` for singular, `v` for plural).
>  **Pronouns** appear not to be used, at least in the simple sentences here.
>  The only other word we see is `naner` meaning "but". It's probably invariant.
>  Word order generally seems to be SVO.
>  Articles appear not to be used.
>  The verb "to be" takes an object, not a complement.

The spelling error:

> I think the -azh in example 3 should be an -osh. It's hard to be certain, but I suspect that in fact -sh is for singular and -zh for plural, so "we" would be -ozh, all the "you"s here are singular, and "you (pl)" would be -azh.

The sentences we were asked to translate:

```
Kielokattaxkov ohtiezh chwtwobebbexkov.
```

> `kielok` is "earthling", `atta` is subject, `ov` is plural.
>  `oh` is "to be", `t` is past, `ezh` is third person plural.
>  `chwtwob` is "being", `ebbe` is object, `ov` is plural.
>  **The earthlings were (the) beings.**

```
Ohdiash rachatebbexkof.
```

> `oh` is "to be", `d` is present, `ash` is second person.
>  `rachat` is "dinner", `ebbe` is object, `of` is singular.
>  **You are dinner**. Uh-oh.

```
Kielokattaxkov ohdiezh daxorpebbexkov.
```

> `kielok` is "earthling", `atta` is subject, `ov` is plural.
>  `oh` is "to be", `d` is present, `ezh` is third person plural.
>  `daxorp` is "food", `ebbe` is object, `ov` is plural.
>  **The earthlings are food-items**. Uh-oh, again.

Comment: Damn it!!! I checked this over like five times and still an error. The long sentence is indeed -ezh. And the -ozh is also an error. That was supposed to be second person plural, but went unsued

Comment: I realized I didn't put any plural "you"s. That was unintentional, I didn't realize I left that out. The original variant was much more complex, but Deus said that it might've been too vague as to what was what, so I cut it down a lot.

Comment: Basically, neither of your spelling error guesses were right. Like 99% of your guesses regarding everything else is correct though

Comment: So, wait, are you saying that both the things I thought might be errors are errors, or that neither of them is an error? Should I be going back and looking for an entirely separate error? I will gladly do that, but not right now because it's way past my bedtime :-).

Comment: Both of them *were* indeed errors, but were unfortunately accidental. I'm mildly dyslexic, so I double-checking stuff like this can be a real nuisance, and sometimes even after checking multiple times I still miss stuff. There is a separate error to find.

Comment: OK, will find the other error tomorrow :-).

Comment: Okay, I fixed one of the lines that created the confusion for you I think. I didn't realize the grammar mattered on that and was a product of an old revision. It should make more sense now

Comment: I also should've added a counter-example to show why it would've been incorrect - again, my fault. Still learning :P

Comment: OK, how about now?

Comment: Yup! There we go. I should've been a bit more consistent in the grammar- I thought of like French and how they don't distinguish between continuous or punctiliar in their present tenses. I probably should've added like more plural forms or perhaps a mixture of both continuous and punctiliar in the examples, it just never occured to me this might be a point of confusion.